# In U-Net, is there a non-linearity (relu) in up-convolution layer?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn

I am doing semantic segmentatio using U-Net. I was wondering whether to include 'relu' activation or not in the up-convolution layer?

````
x = Conv2DTranspose(filters, kernel_size) (x)

OR

x = Conv2DTranspose(filters, kernel_size, activation='relu') (x)

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd not use activation function in these layers because that's how I saw it done first time, but it's probably worth trying since I can't come to a reason why we woudn't use activation function in this layer, it probably shoudn't change the results much.

U-Net anyway has an architecture with convolutions between each upsampling, which use activation functions, so not using activation function in upsampling layers is not a big deal.